# Migration from IBM DB2 z/OS to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, db2, database-migration

I am trying to migrate an IBM DB2 database version 11 (running on z/OS) to PostgreSQL. I tried various tools (EasyFrom, Ispirer, Spectral Core), but they all at least seem to require a ODBC datasource which requires a DB2 Connect license (which seems to be very expensive). Any other ideas / best practices?
Thanks

Comment: I think every SQL dbms supports some way of dumping SQL statements to text files. They usually need some editing when you're moving between vendors, though. Is that an option that's open to you?

Comment: Yes that would also be an option. Of course I am looking for the most cost efficient way to migrate since we are talking about 500 tables with millions or rows.